# Hijri DatePicker in Java

Tags: java, date, javafx, hijri

I'm programming Java program but I'm forced to use *JDK 6*

I need a Library of `JDatePicker` or `JDateChooser` in **Hijri Calendar**

and the way to install it please

Comment: Take a look at ICU4J : http://site.icu-project.org/

Comment: @YCF_L Why do you say, Joda has support for Hijri but Threeten-Backport not? There is but the problem is, both do not support Umalqura variant of Saudi-Arabia. And anyway, the OP asks for UI-libraries containing JDatePicker etc, not just for Hijri calendar implementations.

Comment: @MenoHochschild my bad I removed my comment!